# Input field for time in mm:ss.msms format

Tags: javascript, html, input, time

I am looking for a way for an input field to take in time as a string in the format of mm::ss::msms in a textbox or something.

```
<input type="time">
```

doesn't do the trick since there is no milliseconds and contains AM and PM information which is not needed.

Edit: ms means milliseconds, wasn't sure what the alpha abbreviation for it was

Comment: What does `msms` denote? If it's milliseconds, then the usual notation is `fff` (as it's a 3-digit value), or `v` (PHP's `date` function) or `%OS` (POSIX date format).

Comment: @Dai Haha whoops, been using C++ all day and my brain just thought of :: without thinking. I mean just one colon.

Comment: It's also standard convention to use a dot `.` before milliseconds, not a colon.

Comment: @Dai msms means milliseconds, I wasn't sure what the standard notation for that was

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML5's `<input type="time">` input is intended for time-of-day values, not general time-span values.

You'll want to revert to using `<input type="text">` but with a `pattern=""` value that restricts it to the format you want, which is probably this (regex stolen from https://www.regextester.com/93907 ):

```
<input type="text" pattern="^[0-5][0-9]\:[0-5][0-9]\.[0-9]{1,3}$" />
```

Note this regex isn't perfect, it will allow milliseconds values like `0012` which may or may not be invalid depending on your upstream logic.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! Is there any performance issues I should be aware when using regular expressions in a html tag like that? Or is it not impactful at all?

Comment: @user3019373 The `pattern` expression is only evaluated during form submission. It's not "interactive" the way a WinForms `MaskedTextBox` is, for example. And don't forget to perform server-side validation too!